# Thermal Efficiency

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

For a thermally efficient house, is it better for the windows to be framed with something like aluminium, or steel?

I am considering the thermal conductivities, aluminium has a value of 200, while steel has a value of 40.

Knowing that the greater the thermal conductivity is, the greater the rate of heat transfer, is it better to go with steel as then the outside temperature won't be "fed into" the inside temperature?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct but your economics may be bad. Steel could cost a lot.  Consider vinyl or wood too.  The thickness of the material is a variable.  The net heat loss may be very very small compared to say opening a door for 2 minutes.